# Jsonpath always returning empty list

Tags: java, jsonpath

I am trying to fetch the values from json file with the help of jayway JsonPath. But everytime it returns empty list.

I am trying to use the json path as *.singleAccomViewData

```
import java.util.*;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

public class JSONMapper {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse("D:\\Docs\\search.json");
     List<String> accom = JsonPath.read("D:\\Docs\\search.json", "*.singleAccomViewData");
     System.out.println("accom value: " + accom);
  }
}
```

Below is my JSON File:

```
{
  "searchResult": {
    "singleAccomViewData": null,
    "singleAccomSearch": false,
    "durationSelection": {
      "defaultDisplay": [
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
      ] 
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: that's because `"singleAccomViewData": null` in your JSON

Comment: no, even if i try for others, there also i get the empty list. say for *.singleAccomSearch

Comment: @SeanBright still it gives me the empty list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons why the above is not working:

1. If you are calling `JsonPath.read(String, String)` then the first String is expected to be the Json itself, not a path to a Json file.
2. Using `*` for the root of your JsonPath is not valid, it should be `$`.
3. There is another object above what you are looking for: `searchResult`.

Your final JsonPath should be `$.searchResult.singleAccomViewData`. Fix the above issues and it should work as expected.